# Intersection point between a line and plane: what's wrong with my calculation?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to calculate the intersection point between a line and a plane, but apparently there is something wrong with my calculation and I don't know what exactly.

The exercise goes as follows:

The line l passes through (2,2,2) and (−3,3,0). Determine the intersection point p of the line l and the plane V given by the equation x + y + 2z = −24.

My calculation:

Vector corresponding to the lines: <-5, 1, -2>
Parametric equation: (2,2,2) + t<-5, 1, -2> = <2-5t, 2+t, 2-2t>
Which results into x = 2-5t, y = 2+t and z = 2-2t
Filling those values in x + y + 2z = −24 gives t = 2
Filling T into the equations of x, y and z results into <-8, 4, -2>, which is according to my calculation the intersection point between the line and the plane, but apparently it is not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x+y+2z=-24 \Rightarrow 2-5t+2+t+4-4t=-24 \Rightarrow 8-8t=-24  \\ \Rightarrow -8t=-32 \Rightarrow t=4$$

Comment: Ah apparently I made a silly mistake, thanks for the solution!