# How do I determine the intersection point of a line $l$ and a plane $V$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

The line $l$ passes trough $(1,-4,0)$ and $(-4,4,-2)$. The given plane is: $3x+4y-4z=37$.

The first thing I thought to do is writing the two points as a vector.
I came up with $(-5,8,-2)$.
I tried using the vector for the following parameter equation:
$(-5,8,-2)+t(3,4,-4)$ but apparently this is wrong.
Could someone help me out?

Comment: Surely there are examples of similar problems in the coursework leading up to this exercise. Review it and see if you can find one. You might also look through the handy list of related problems at right, such as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/937207/265466.

Comment: Well, you did come up with the direction vector correctly. However, the parametrization is wrong, it should be:
$$(x,y,z)=(1,-4,0)+t(-5,8,-2)$$
Notice how when $t=0$ you have the point $(1,-4,0)$ and when $t=1$ you have $(-4,4,-2)$, so this is indeed a parametrization of the line $l$.

Comment: now solve for $t$ that makes $(x,y,z)$ on the plane

Comment: This would be (3,4,-4) looking at the given plane am I right?

Comment: No. The point $(3,4,-4)$ is not even on the plane since $3\cdot 3+4\cdot 4-4\cdot (-4)=41\neq 37$ (nor is it on the line, in fact). The parametrization of the line I gave you tells you that $x=1-5t$, $y=-4+8t$, $z=-2t$. Now, for what value of $t$ is that on the plane $3x+4y-4z=37$? From that value of $t$, you then have the point such that they intersect.

Comment: Yup I made a stupid mistake there sorry, I came up with t=2 and when I fill this in the parametrization i get the vector (-9,12,-4) would this be right?

Comment: I filled in the vector in the plane and it is equal to 37! Thank you for your patience it is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direction vector: $\vec d=(-5,8,-2)$.

Line: $\vec r = (1,-4,0)+t (-5,8,-2)$.

Plane: $3x+4y-4z=37$;

Solve for $t$:

$3(1-5t)+4(-4+8t)-4(-2t)=37;$

And then?

Comment: I came up with t=2 and when I fill this in the parametrization i get the vector (-9,12,-4) would this be right?

Comment: Nawin.Check if (-9,12,4) satisfies 3x+4y-4z=37; Does it?

Comment: IT DOES! Thank you so much for your patience with me. I am pretty weak with maths and my teacher usually gets angry with me when I take too long. This way I try to improve my maths and I absolutely love this community helping me!

Comment: Welcome.Keep going, With a little practice things come easier:)